# How to parse complex string with dynamic symbols before and after the text

Tags: php

```
2-(Диметиламино) этанол (2-(Dimethylamino)ethanol): инструкция по применению, противопоказания и состав
```

I have this string, I want to parse the cyrillic name with the number and all the symbols before and after including spaces that may be `2-(Диметиламино)` and the latin name that is `(2-(Dimethylamino)ethanol)`

but every time the name is different,

```
13-цис-Ретиноевая кислота (13-cys-Retinoic acid): инструкция по применению, противопоказания и состав
```

now the cyrillic name is `13-цис-Ретиноевая кислота`, and the latin is `(13-cys-Retinoic acid)`

I'am using this to parse it:

```
preg_match ('/[\p{Cyrillic}]+/u', $chemical_text, $matches);

preg_match('/[\p{Latin}]+/u', $chemical_text, $matches);
```

What I don't know is how to parse those names with whetever symbols appear like `-, _, @, (, )` and so on

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need to concern yourself with the symbols that much. This type of input can be parsed with

```
/(.*)\s+\((?=\P{Cyrillic}+:)([^:]*)\)/u
```

The first capturing group `(.*?)` matches the Cyrillic text non-greedily up to the point where the space-and-paren delimiter appears; then the positive lookahead `(?=\P{Cyrillic}+:)` ensures that from that point onward and until the next double colon there is no Cyrillic text at all. The second capturing group `([^:]*)` then greedily matches everything it can until the combination of paren-and-double-colon that delimits the English name.

**Update: an alternative**

```
/(\P{Latin}*)\s+\((\P{Cyrillic}*)\)\P{L}*\s+/u
```

This regex matches text of the form

```
<cyrillic> <whitespace> (<latin>) [symbols] <whitespace>
```

where `[symbols]` can appear optionally. Perhaps it would be a better fit for some kinds of inputs.

Comment: This produces "2-(Диметиламино) этанол" instead of "2-(Диметиламино)"

Comment: @user4035: I think that's the whole idea. 2-(Диметиламино) by itself is meaningless (well, not meaningless, but it doesn't tell you much about the chemical compound).

Comment: Yes, as it corresponds to "(2-(Dimethylamino)ethanol)" his regexp didn't catch " этанол"

Comment: Диэтилбензимидазолия трийодид (Diaethylbensimidasolium tryiodide) - somehow this string gives me an empty result

Comment: @user2507316: Is there a double colon at the end? In both of your original examples there is, so the regex uses it.

Comment: hmmm really said the string differs everytime, there may be or not may be colons or other symbols...is it possible to parse something like that?

Comment: @user2507316: Well, anything is possible but you have to make some assumptions. I added another regex that may serve better.